# remove include path in nvcc

Tags: cuda, gpu, nvidia, nvcc

I am trying to extend the vector support by CUDA, e.g, overriding operators in vector structures. I could just do it by modifying the default vector_types.h file. However it is not possible in a multi-user environment where I don't have the permission to modify it.

Hence, I decided to create a new vector_types.h and do not include the original vector_types.h. But it seems nvcc automatically includes this file even I don't include it in my code. So my question is that is there anyway to change this behavior of nvcc?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I think the short answer to your question is no.  `nvcc` is a compiler driver tool, so it does quite a few steps "under the hood".  If you want to see what is going on, read the `nvcc` [manual](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-compiler-driver-nvcc/index.html#axzz2z0cavESl) and learn about `dryrun`.  But I don't think you will find a standard method (e.g. compile switch) to tell `nvcc` not to include the `vector_types.h` file from the standard system include path.  You could try overriding the system include path `-isystem` but you will need to have basically a full local install of CUDA.

Comment: If you are in a multi-user environment and can't change the system version of CUDA, if you have enough disk space you can download the CUDA toolkit and install a local copy, and with appropriate path definitions work from that copy, which you can modify as you see fit.

Comment: Thank for the comments I guess I will have to look at the manual to see if there is a solution or not. Just put your comments as an answer I will accept it if I can't find a solution from the manual.

Answer (score 1):

You can create separate header file and include `vector_types.h` there:

```
// vector_types_ext.h

#include <vector_types.h>

__device__ float4 operator +(float4 a, float4 b)
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: OK that might work but what if I want to overload a subscript ([]) operator? Such a prototype should be __device__ int &operator[] (int i). And this must be in the struct declaration I think.